# How to shut down mongos server?

Tags: mongodb

I found out that `mongod` has `--shutdown` to cleanly shut down a server, what is the corresponding command for a `mongos` server?

The only way i found out was to simply find the PID for the server and `kill -9` it, but it seems like this is not the smartest way to do it.

Using mongodb version 3.0 btw.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps:

1. Login to `mongos`
2. switch to `admin` database
3. run `db.shutdownServer()`